# windows batch script get environment variable changes

Tags: windows, batch, puppet

I have a script that does something like

```
setx %PATH% %PATH%;%ANOTHER_VAR%

echo %PATH%
```

When I echo the path, it does not include %ANOTHER_VAR%. is there a way to ensure the new variables are reflected the second time I echo %PATH%

EDIT: I'm writing a puppet script that calls 2 separate exec commands. The first calls setx on a variable. Since the second one is accessed in a new exec command, I would expect it to have access to the newly set variable, but it does not.

I have also tried just creating a variable in script1 and accessing that from script2, but it's not accessible (as expected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, setx sets the variable via the registry (see this [article](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)). It requires the start of a new command shell to see the results.

If you want to change the path setting under the current command session use `set path=%path%;%another_variable%`.

In response to the comment, this is from setx /?:

NOTE: 1) SETX writes variables to the master environment in the registry.

2) On a local system, variables created or modified by this tool
     will be available in future command windows but **not in the
     current CMD.exe command window**.

If you want to change the variable in the current command session, use plain SET.

Below is the output from my system:

```
C:\Windows\system32>set path2=%cd%

C:\Windows\system32>set path2
path2=C:\Windows\system32

C:\Windows\system32>cd drivers

C:\Windows\System32\drivers>set path2=%path2%;%cd%

C:\Windows\System32\drivers>set path2
path2=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\System32\drivers
```

Comment: Hmmm..I must be doing something else wrong. I have one script that is calling the other 2 and the 2nd script does not pick up the changes via setx. I might just be expecting something that shouldn't happen.